# escape "" character in php

Tags: php, laravel, sanitization

How do I sanitize this in PHP so that taking a substring from it won't turn it into a non-string?

```
// Returns b"—¡ breaks my c" which is not a string
dump(substr('this  breaks my code', 7, 14));
```

I'm using Laravel so if there's a sanitize function in Laravel somewhere I could use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `substr` try using [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

substr is not designed for multi-byte strings

Comment: now that's elitis coding (https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) how's my answer different then the other 2? just that I have "just" 1K reputation?

Comment: thanks man! read that blog post, I relate to it both as a relative noob and as someone that likes helping noobs..

Comment: tbh, I originally went to post `Use mb_substr() instead.` but then SO wouldn't let me post, so I added an example. I don't think you got downvoted for your rep.

Comment: Maybe, but people shouldn't downvote just because there is another answer that's better. There is even a tooltip on the down arrow that says "this answer is not useful". This answer is still correct so I don't get it why someone would downvote it

Answer (score 3):

`substr()` operates on a byte level, heritage of the C programming language. If (make sure that is the case!) you are using UTF-8 as encoding, one symbol can take multiple bytes. In that case, you should install the mbstring extension and use `mb_substr()` instead.